# Is there an alternative for the function take() from angular 2 in angular 8?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am having trouble with code from angular 2. I am using angular 8 and i keep getting this error on console

ERROR Error: "Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: item$.take is not a function
updateItemQuantity

here is my method

```
private async updateItemQuantity(product: Product, change: number){
    let cartId = await this.getOrCreateCartId();
    let item$ = this.getItem(cartId, product.$key);
    item$.take(1).subscribe(item => {
      item$.update({product: product, quantity: (item.quantity || 0) + 
      change});
    });
  }
```

Comment: Does adding `import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';` fix the error?

Comment: no, it is already added at the top.

Comment: what is getItem returning

Comment: private getItem(cartId: string, productId: string){
        return this.db.object('/shopping-carts/' + cartId + '/items/' + productId);
      }  i think it returns an AngularFireObject<unknown>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your comment you that what `item$` gets its data from:

```
getItem(cartId: string, productId: string){ 
   return this.db.object('/shopping-carts/' + cartId + '/items/' + productId); 
}
```

You need to add `valueChanges()` (or `snapshotChanges` depending on your requirement).
Adding `valueChanges` now gives you an observable:

```
return this.db.object(...).valueChanges();
```

Then like mentioned in other answer, you need to use `pipe`:

```
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';

// ...

item$.pipe(
  take(1)
).subscribe(item => { // ...
```

Comment: Great, glad to hear! Please consider accepting the answer by clicking the grey tick under the voting of this answer, as it solved your issue :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to put take inside of pipe

```
item$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe()
```

Comment: now i get "ERROR Error: "Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: item$.pipe is not a function
updateItemQuantity"

Comment: @IDavidJr_ are you sure `item$` is an observable?

Comment: @IDavidJr_, you need change the imports from 'rxjs', because from Angular 2 to Angular 8 change Rxjs 5 to Rxjs 6. So you need import form 'rxjs' the "creations method" Subject, forkJoin,of... and from 'rxjs/operators' the operators: map, swichMap,tap, merge.. see https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md